# IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I want to implement bottom navigation using view pager, but my app crashes with the below exception.
Not able to find the exact issue here, can someone please help me in this ?

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: RepositoriesFragment{6b6a2f2} (3aaac6af-92a3-47bc-b3e5-fa3b29ac5d52) id=0x7f080166 android:switcher:2131231078:0}
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.addFragment(FragmentStore.java:67)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1563)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:405)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2167)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1990)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1945)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1847)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)

Here is my HomePagerAdapter where I have implemented: FragmentPagerAdapter

```
class HomePageAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

private val instantiatedFragments: SparseArray<WeakReference<Fragment>> = SparseArray()

companion object {
    const val FRAGMENT_INDEX_REPO = 0
    const val FRAGMENT_INDEX_DEV = 1
    const val NUM_OF_ITEMS = 2
    const val FRAGMENT_DEV_TITLE = "Developers"
    const val FRAGMENT_REPO_TITLE = "Repositories"
}

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    return if (position == FRAGMENT_INDEX_REPO) {
        RepositoriesFragment.newInstance()
    } else {
        DevelopersFragment.newInstance()
    }
}

override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
    val fragment = super.instantiateItem(container, position) as Fragment
    instantiatedFragments.put(
        position,
        WeakReference(fragment)
    )
    return fragment
}

override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, obj: Any) {
    instantiatedFragments.remove(position)
    super.destroyItem(container, position, obj)
}

override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
    return if (position == FRAGMENT_INDEX_REPO) {
        FRAGMENT_REPO_TITLE
    } else {
        FRAGMENT_DEV_TITLE
    }
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return NUM_OF_ITEMS
}
```

}

Comment: Just remove the functions `instantiateItem` and `destroyItem` and it'll work

Comment: yeah, tried it , still getting same exception.

Comment: That is very interesting, but it also means that the exception comes from the code that manages the PagerAdapter

Comment: Earlier it was working, I didn't make any change in HomePageAdapter class , don't know why this error is coming ?

Comment: Without knowing the class that creates `HomePageAdapter` I can't tell you

Comment: Okay, this is my HomeActivity which is creating the HomePageAdapter:    homePageAdapter = HomePageAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        view_pager.adapter = homePageAdapter

Comment: For me the same issue started after i added Koin to inject my viewmodels. Found no solution.

Comment: Also facing same issue, and especially on android 10 and 9 , i wonder if  `ViewPager2` would solve this issue.

Comment: Also facing this issue. I have been using the same adapter for 3 years without any problems and now, I have crashes from android 8,9,10.